# Connect two bones to one

Tags: bones

I have two separate bones, the heads of which I'd like to connect to the tail of a single bone as shown.[image]

Is this possible? Or is there an analogue?

Comment: actually what you want to do is the opposite, you'd like to stick the tails of the 2 bottom bones to the head of the top bone, but it won't look like your drawing, plus it will only follow the head if you give it some sort of constraint, so maybe you should work another way around and talk in detail about what you're trying to achieve, i.e. your final purpose

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to connect 2 bones at the tip together, you would have to rotate the bones by 180°. May I ask what the purpose is? Maybe I could help you with your problem.

Comment: So the rule is explicitly every tail can have only one attached head, but a head can have many attached tails? Just so I'm clear on it. I've got two pistons attached to a sphere. When the sphere moves each piston must also move, and I fear having two bones in one object is going to be problematic, so I'd live the piston paths to merge into a single bone I can assign to the sphere.

Comment: You'd better explain what is your final purpose, please edit your question with more details